# ActiveMQ prefetchSize over multiple queues

Tags: jms, activemq-classic

I have consumers that handle jobs that take a lot of time and resources.
So it is unreasonable that a consumer handles more than 1 job at a time.

Every consumer is assigned to multiple queues. The relationship between consumers and queues is n <-> m.

To avoid a backlog of messages at each consumer, I use the setting `queue?consumer.prefetchSize=1` ([ActiveMQ docs](https://activemq.apache.org/what-is-the-prefetch-limit-for)).

My problem is the following:

- It is possible that a consumer prefetches messages from multiple queues
- While it can work on one of the messages, the other message(s) will be lying around in its prefetch buffer
- Other consumers that are free to work on the message have no way to receive the message as it is already prefetched

I know that one solution is to use `prefetchSize=0` and poll synchronously.

Is there another way to handle this issue in ActiveMQ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you know that your application takes a message and spends a large amount of time processing it then a zero prefetch consumer is a sensible option as it prevents another message from arriving and sitting idle in the prefetch buffer of the consumer which prevents anyone else from processing it.

Comment: I agree that it's possible, but it makes my application more complicated. E.g. having a thread open to poll from the broker instead of just receiving the message when it is available. I wish there was something like a prefetchSize over all consumed queues.

Comment: I decided to use this approach - set prefetch to 0 and poll from the queue in each producer. Has been working well so far :)